About graph plots with multiple models in LMFIT
Here's my code
x_1=np.array(x)
y_1=np.array(y)

exp_model = ExponentialModel(prefix='exp_')
pv1_model = PseudoVoigtModel(prefix='pv1_')
pv2_model = PseudoVoigtModel(prefix='pv2_')
pv3_model = PseudoVoigtModel(prefix='pv3_')

mod = exp_model+pv1_model+pv2_model+pv3_model

pars=exp_model.guess(y_1, x=x_1) #background
pars.update(pv1_model.make_params())
pars['pv1_center'].set(value=1483, min=1433, max=1533)
pars.update(pv2_model.make_params())
pars['pv2_center'].set(value=1150, min=1100, max=1200)
pars.update(pv3_model.make_params())
pars['pv3_center'].set(value=1050, min=1000, max=1100)

out = mod.fit(y_1, pars, x=x_1)

print(out.fit_report())

I want to extract the data for pv1_mod from the fitting data
(I want to plot the pv1_model fitting data separately, and to fill the graph)
Example images from http://emilygraceripka.com/blog/16
Thanks!
However, the out.best_fit data contains values for sum of all models.
Is there a good solution?
